# Java Schedule Generator Not Outputting Enough

Tags: java

I am working on a java sports schedule generator , and my issue is that it is not generating enough games, I have it (I think) set for 32 days and one game per team per day, yet for some reason never outputs that many, varying between 17-29. I've gone through this several times, and I still can not figure out the problem. Please help!
This is what I have so far: Thanks in advance!

```
    public class FourThirtyTwoSched {
//Who has the team played and how many times
static int[][] schedulePlayed = new int[4][4];

//Has the team played today?
static int[][] playedToday = new int [32][4];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Initiate Random objects
    Random rand = new Random(4);
    Random replace = new Random(4);
    //Sets the arrays
    //Column = reference team
    for(int i = 0; i < schedulePlayed.length; i++){
        schedulePlayed[i][0] = 8;
        schedulePlayed[i][1] = 8;
        schedulePlayed[i][2] = 8;
        schedulePlayed[i][3] = 8;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j 
            < 32; j++){
        playedToday[j][0] = 1;
        playedToday[j][1] = 1;
        playedToday[j][2] = 1;
        playedToday[j][3] = 1;
    }

    //Initiate Time
    int day = 0;

        while(day < 32){
        while((playedToday[day][0] + playedToday[day][1] + playedToday[day][2] + playedToday[day][3]) != 0){

        int vs = 0;
        int team = 0;
        vs = rand.nextInt(4);
        team = rand.nextInt(4);
        //ensure random is valid
        while(playedToday[day][vs] == 0 || schedulePlayed[vs][team] == 0 || playedToday[day][team] == 0){
            vs = replace.nextInt(4);
            team = replace.nextInt(4);  }            
        if (playedToday[day][vs] > 0 && schedulePlayed[vs][team] > 0 && playedToday[day][team] > 0){
            //Only prints if not bye
            if (true) {
            System.out.println(team + " v. " + vs);
            }}
    //prevents a team from playing multiple times per day- or against same team more than 8 times
            schedulePlayed[vs][team]--;
            playedToday[day][vs]--;
            playedToday[day][team]--;

        }
        //day count up one
        day++;      
        System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: Thanks, I ran it through Eclipse debugger, which netted a useful find- the while loop evaluating the sum had issues causing the loop to not execute the right number of times. It still generates the wrong number of games now, but averages out to the right amount.